# Binning 1:9 -> bin of equal number cell array

Tags: matlab, bin, binning

following simple problem: I want to put a vector into a cell array `groups` of *equal sized bins*.

I have troubles solving, and I have a strong feeling could be a one-liner, here's how far I've gotten:

```
nums=1:9; %numbers to bin
categories=discretize(nums,3); %put nums in 3 equal groups
groups=mat2cell(x); % should return: {1:3,4:6,7:9}
```

what am I missing?

The solution should work for any 1D vector containing numbers, bin it into as-equal-sized-bins as possible (any solution works); the output should be a cell array of the respective bins.

Comment: Are the bins built using the numbers in the original order, or in increasing order of their values? What should the output be if the bin size doesn't divide the number of elements?

Comment: The categories assigned to elements of `nums` by `categories=discretize(nums,3);` are `{1:2,3:5,6:9}`, not `{1:3,4:6,7:9}`. Which is your intended result?

Comment: @Will You are correct. The intended result is to have as-equal-sized bins possible (with a fleixble bin-size). Using discretize was the result of googling that and reading `[Y,E] = discretize(X,N) divides the range of X into N uniform bins, and also returns the bin edges E.` from the documentation, unintended result, apologies

Comment: @LuisMendo the order doesn't matter, the output size I guess the closes possible, i.e. say 10 -> bins of 3 -> 3,3,4 bins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
result = num2cell(reshape(1:9,3,[]),1);
```

If the array size isn't divisible by the number of bins you can use [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) and [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
nbins = 3;
a= [2 3 1 8 7 6 9 8 1];
result = mat2cell(a,1,histcounts(1:numel(a),nbins));
```